# How to make bs4 code not look ugly as hell

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, readability

I'm making a scraping project with bs4 and I simply cannot see a way to make it less eye-bleeding. Everything looks like this:

```
try:
    max_tweet_date = max(
        [tweet_date_to_datetime(timeline_item.find('span', {'class': 'tweet-date'}).find('a')['title'])
         for timeline_item in tweets_or_replies_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'timeline-item'})]
    )
except AttributeError:
    print('No tweets or replies')
    print()
    neo4j_database.set_user_updated_now(current_user)
except IndexError:
    print('Not enough tweets or no tweets')
    print()
    neo4j_database.set_user_updated_now(current_user)
except ValueError:
    print("Cannot recognise dates, skipping")
    print()
    neo4j_database.set_user_updated_now(current_user)

if is_tweet_too_old(max_tweet_date):
    print('User is inactive, deleting')
    print()
    neo4j_database.delete_user(current_user)
```

There are always tons of exceptions that need to be handled and the way it handles attributes is begging to be contained in a separate function.
Are there any helpful patterns or maybe other parsing libraries that can help clean up this mess?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform both `find()` and `find_all()` methods to standalone functions with meaningful names.

Comment: Yeah, it would make sense if I used the same attributes multiple times, or even the same attribute names, but really every find is unique, so I would have to create tons of functions to cover all of this. And I doubt this would help the readability.

Comment: Usually works for me, when I open the code months later, it helps me to understand what every find() does. And easily to find which one doesn't work (if the target website was changed). In my code it usually looks like: `def get_max_tweet_date(soup)` `max_tweet_date = get_max_tweet_date(soup)`. Also, I try to avoid using try-except and detect the special cases that raise those exceptions. I don't really know what else to recommend.